# Count unique pairs and store counts in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

My question is similar to [stackoverflow.com/q/7549410](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7549410)

I have paired data which look like this:

```
ID   ATTR
3    10
1    20
1    20
4    30
```

I want to count the unique pairs and store those frequency counts in a matrix like this:

```
     10   20   30
1 |   0    2    0
3 |   1    0    0
4 |   0    0    1
```

Alternatively, if it's known that ID takes values in {1, 2, 3, 4} while ATTR in {0, 10, 20, 30} then I want a matrix as such:

```
     0   10   20   30
1 |  0    0    2    0
2 |  0    0    0    0
3 |  0    1    0    0
4 |  0    0    0    1
```

**Question**: What's the fastest way to do both of them in Python or NumPy?

I have tried using Pandas but I get an empty DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([[3, 10], [1, 20], [1, 20], [4, 30]])
x.pivot_table(index = 0, columns = 1, fill_value = 0, aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Comment: Is this pandas?

Comment: `x.pivot_table(index=0, columns=1, values=1, aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Pls see my updated question. It's not a duplicated question since there are 2 kinds of matrices I'm seeking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to perform a cross tabulation, followed by a reindexing operation. For the cross tabulation, there are many ways to skin a cat.

First, using `pivot_table` -

```
v = x.pivot_table(
      index=0, 
      columns=1, 
      values=1, 
      aggfunc='size', 
      fill_value=0
)
```

Or, `pd.crosstab` -

```
v = pd.crosstab(x[0], x[1])
```

Or, `set_index` + `get_dummies` + `sum(level=0)`

```
v = pd.get_dummies(x.set_index(0)[1]).sum(level=0)
```

Or, `get_dummies` + `dot` -

```
v = pd.get_dummies(x[0]).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(x[1]))
```

```
v

   10  20  30
1   0   2   0
3   1   0   0
4   0   0   1
```

Next, call `reindex` on `v` -

```
v.reindex(index=range(1, 5), columns=range(0, 40, 10), fill_value=0)

1  0   10  20  30
0                
1   0   0   2   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using category

```
df.ID=df.ID.astype('category',categories=[1,2,3,4])
df.ATTR=df.ATTR.astype('category',categories=[0,10,20,30])

pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.ATTR)
Out[1143]: 
ATTR  0   10  20  30
ID                  
1      0   0   2   0
2      0   0   0   0
3      0   1   0   0
4      0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Categories is just as clever, and would work just as well for strings. Nicely done.